# python len from SQL query returning differing int values

Tags: python, sql, flask

I have a simple sqlite query set up to use parameters from a html form that I reference. When I run this Flask web app and pass through a username that already exists in my database, I get two different values for the len function dependent on whether or not I assign this function to a variable.

```
username_match = db.execute('SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = ?', (request.form.get('username'),))

match = len(username_match.fetchall())
    
print(match)
print(len(username_match.fetchall()))
```

The `print(match)` returns a 1 when a matching username is queried, but for some reason `print(len(username_match.fetchall()))` returns a value of 0 for the same username query.

Comment: `fetchall()` returns all the records that haven't been fetched yet. The first one fetches everything, the second time has nothing left to fetch.

Comment: The variable has nothing to do with it. You would see the same problem if you wrote `print(len(username_match.fetchall()))` twice.

Comment: @mechanical_meat Why do you think they need to get the length of the column? I think they want to know how many rows were returned.

Comment: Aren't userids unique? So the query can either return 1 row or 0. So why not just use `fetchone()` and check whether it returned a row or `None`?

Comment: @Barmar: ah, seems you're right about the length they're after! and interesting how `.fetchall()` works; i should've known about that. i appreciate the clarification.